# Enabling display_errors from inside code

Tags: php, fatal-error

Our development server has suffered some configuration mismatch on recent update to PHP 5.3, and now I can't see any errors – any time I hit a fatal/parse error, I just see a blank page.

Now, I know how to enable error reporting in normal cases, but I don't have access to php.ini and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` obviously doesn't cut it if the page has hit a parse error.

Is there any other way to set / override php.ini's settings, via .htaccess perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in .htaccess, you can put:

```
php_value display_errors 1
```

...As long as no one has put the following in a non-htaccess Apache config file:

```
php_admin_value display_errors 0
```

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) for more info.